# Place a border around X Y position on page

Tags: jquery, html, css

Using CSS or jQuery, I would like to place a small box on a given top left position within a div. So if I have a div called `mydiv`, I would to place a border in an XY position inside of this div. How might I achieve my goal?

Comment: Can you make a mockup? I'm not seeing what a `border` is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Would an absolutely positioned div within mydiv be satisfactory?

Check out [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Q4kQT/1/) to see what I mean.

Here is a [sample with float](http://jsfiddle.net/Q4kQT/2/) rather than absolute positioning. Apologies if this isn't what you wanted - I'm only partially sure this is what you want. I can't visualize what you need it for.

edit: float doesn't allow specifying coordinates as `position: absolute` does, but it *does* offer content wrapping in return for that compromise. It really depends on what you're trying to do here.